# Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT] , Why this error occurs?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, mongoose, mern

I am getting this error while trying to add authentication for my project.

This controller has a middleware that authenticates the user.

```
exports.fetchOne = (req, res) => {
  const _id = req.params.id;

  console.log("fetch One");
  try {
    collectionsModel.findById(_id).then((data) => {
      if (!data) {
        res.status(404).json({ message: "Data not found" });
      }
      console.log(data);
      res.send(data);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
};
```

The problem here is this controller works fine when Authentication middleware is not kept,But it gives this error.

```
node:internal/errors:490
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

This is the authUser middleware

```
const authUser = (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("Auth middleware");
  if (
    req.headers &&
    req.headers.authorization &&
    req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[0] === "JWT"
  ) {
    jwt.verify(
      req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1],
      process.env.JWT_SECRET,
      function (err, verifyToken) {
        if (err) {
          res.status(401).json({ message: "Invalid JWT Token" });
        }

        userModel
          .findById(verifyToken.id)
          .then((user) => {
            if (!user) {
              res.status(401).json({ message: "Invalid User" });
            }
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            res.status(500).json({ message: err.message || "Server Error" });
          });
      }
    );
  } else {
    res.status(403).json({ message: "Token not present" });
  }

  next();
};
```

the console is printing the data and also the "fetch One" , But the data is not been sent to client(React) properly.

What can i do for this?

I tried by changing the unwanted next() in middleware, Now the authentication middleware has a next() at its buttom, Still the error remains the same.

Answer (score 2):

Because when there is no data you are trying to send a response twice.

```
collectionsModel.findById(_id).then((data) => {
      if (!data) {
        res.status(404).json({ message: "Data not found" });
      }
      console.log(data);
      res.send(data);
    });
```

Add a return if there is no data

```
collectionsModel.findById(_id).then((data) => {
      if (!data) {
        return res.status(404).json({ message: "Data not found" });
      }
      console.log(data);
      res.send(data);
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

But still i get the error while using authUser middleware,
I have added the code of middleware to the question. Does that have any error?
I have also tried adding the return inside if in authUser, Then it does not even passed to the controller.